# Maximum modulus theorem within a triangle

Tags: complex-analysis

Now suppose $z_1z_2z_3z_4$ is a square whose center is the origin $O$, $f \in H(D) \subset C(\overline{D})$, $$M=\max_{|z|=1}|f(z)|,m=\max_{z \in [z_1,z_2]}|f(z)|$$, where $[z_1,z_2]$ means the segment $\overline{z_1z_2}$ prove that
$$(i)|f(0)| \le m^{\frac{1}{4}}M^{\frac{3}{4}}$$
$$(ii)|f(z)| \le m^{\frac{1}{4}}M^{\frac{3}{4}}$$ within the triangle $\Delta Oz_1z_2$

It's easy to prove $(i)$, we only need to consider $F(z)=f(z)f(ze^{i\frac{\pi}{2}})f(ze^{i\pi})f(ze^{i\frac{3\pi}{2}})$ and apply maximum modulus theorem on it. Then set z=0,done.

But as for the second problem, I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually pick a random point $z_0 \in [0,z_1] \subset [0,z_2]$, construct a line through $z_0$ and perpendicular to $Oz_1$ which intersects with $[z_1,z_2]$ at $P$ and with $[z_1,z_4]$ at $Q$. Then we have a square $Qz_1PR \subset \overline{D}$ centered at $z_0$. Denote $S$ the interior of the square.

Consider $F \in H(S) \cap C(\overline{S})$:
$$ F(z)=f(z)f(z_0+(z-z_0)e^{i \frac{\pi}{2}})f(z_0+(z-z_0)e^{i \pi})f(z_0+(z-z_0)e^{i \frac{3 \pi}{4}}),z \in \partial S
$$
Simlilar to $(i)$, we have $|F(z)| \le mM^3$. By Maximum modulus theorem, we have $|F(z)| \le mM^3$
Set $z=z_0$ and $|F(z_0)| \le mM^3$, hence $|f(z_0)| \le m^{\frac{1}{4}}M^{\frac{3}{4}}$

By random choice of $z_0$, $|f(z)| \le m^{\frac{1}{4}}M^{\frac{3}{4}}, z \in \partial (\Delta Oz_1z_2)$.
Apply Maximum modulus theorem again and we have the conclusion $|f(z)| \le m^{\frac{1}{4}}M^{\frac{3}{4}}, z\in \Delta Oz_1z_2$.