holomorphic function on the square

Let $D$ be a square with edges  ${z}_{1}, {z}_{2}, {z}_{3}, {z}_{4}$ and center $0$, $f$ is holomorphic on $D$, and continuous on $\bar{D}$. Let $M=\max_{z\in \bar{D}}|f(z)|$, $m=\max_{z\in [z_1,z_2]}|f(z)|$. Prove that
(i) $\left| {f\left( 0\right) }\right|  \leq  {m}^{\frac{1}{4}}{M}^{\frac{3}{4}}$;
(ii) On the closed triangle $\triangle  O{z}_{1}{z}_{2}$ we still have $\left| {f\left( z\right) }\right|  \leq  {m}^{\frac{1}{4}}{M}^{\frac{3}{4}}$.

What is the idea? My attempt: $f(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta}d \zeta$. If we estimate it roughly, $|f(0)|\leq \frac{1}{2\pi}[\frac{m}{1}\cdot 2+6\frac{M}{1}]=\frac{m+3M}{\pi}$.
I only see the estimate in the calculus, $f(x+h)=\cdots$, taking $h$ suitably...

Looks like a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1735436/42969 to me.
